# Java taglib to perform grep?

Tags: css, regex, jsp, taglib

I need to implement a jsp page which basically 'joins' multiple CSS files.
Due to the nature of CSS I cannot simply do:

```
<jsp:include page="one.css"/>
<jsp:include page="two.css"/>
<jsp:include page="three.css"/>
```

since any @import statement within two.css and three css would be ignored ! (they must appear before any other CSS statement)

So I'd like to do something like:

```
<%-- first all the @import directives --%>
<t:grep expr="@import">
  <jsp:include page="one.css"/>
  <jsp:include page="two.css"/>
  <jsp:include page="three.css"/>
</t:grep>

<%-- then everything (duplicate @import are ignored) --%>
<jsp:include page="one.css"/>
<jsp:include page="two.css"/>
<jsp:include page="three.css"/>
```

question is:

- is anyone aware of a java/JSP TAGLIB which can perform the above task?
- any good alternative to the above appoach?

P.s: I could easily implement such a taglib but I'm not willing to re-invent the wheel !!

Comment: It sounds that you are trying to re-invent the wheel with this approach.  Perhaps if you explain what problem you are trying to solve (i.e. why you cannot include the necessary files one after the other) -

Comment: @ochi I'm just using a 3rd party component which allows to specify 1 CSS to perform customization. We don't want to customize this component otherwise upgrades etc... will become more compliacted.
Furthermore css grouping has lots of advantages in terms of page load times in case of "small" CSS ("small" depends on the ratio between latency and bandwidth) and we use it to join CSS from multiple libs into a single CSS.